# Trim values of String fields of a case class

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am writing a generic function using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) that takes an instance of a `case class` and trims all values of fields that are string. The case class can have optional fields, nested objects, lists etc.

I have a case class `Person`.

```
case class Person(name: Option[String], address: List[String], friends: List[Person])
```

The function that I currently have:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist._

  object trimmer extends Poly1 {
    implicit val stringOptCase = at[Option[String]](_.map(_.trim))
    implicit val stringListCase = at[List[String]](_.map(_.trim))
    implicit def skipCase[A] = at[A](identity)
  }

  def trimStringValues[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
                                     gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
                                     mapper: Mapper.Aux[trimmer.type, R, R]
  ) = gen.from(mapper(gen.to(a)))
```

When I use the above function, it only works for the root level `name` field of class `Person`. It doesn't work for list or object field.

```
val person = Person(name = Some(" john "), address = List(" ny"," vegas "), friends = List(Person(Some(" alicia"), List(" peter"), Nil)))

trimStringValues(person) // Person(Some(john),List(ny, vegas),List(Person(Some( alicia),List( peter),List())))
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it does seem to be working on `address` as well as `name` in your commented output, which is to be expected. It's not working on `friends` because `List[Person]` matches the `skipCase` case—it's neither an `Option[String]` or a `List[String]`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use Shapeless's `everywhere` combinator. Given your code above, you can write the following:

```
scala> shapeless.everywhere(trimmer)(person)
res1: Person = Person(Some(john),List(ny, vegas),List(Person(Some(alicia),List(peter),List())))
```

In fact you can accomplish the same thing with an even simpler `trimmer` implementation:

```
object trimStrings extends Poly1 {
  implicit val stringCase: Case.Aux[String, String] = at[String](_.trim)
}
```

Or equivalently but even more concisely:

```
import shapeless.poly.->

object trimStrings extends (String -> String)(_.trim)
```

And then:

```
scala> shapeless.everywhere(trimStrings)(person)
res5: Person = Person(Some(john),List(ny, vegas),List(Person(Some(alicia),List(peter),List())))
```

If you wanted more control over exactly which strings are trimmed, you could return to your original implementation and either add an explicit `List[Person]` case, or a more generic case that would match types like this and apply `trimmer` recursively. Since you say you want to trim *all* strings, though, `everywhere` sounds like it's what you want.